# Octave 6.2.0 not working on Debian Bullseye 11.3 running on WSL1

Tags: debian, qt5, octave, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bullseye

As of June 2022, Octave 6.2.0 appears to have a broken dependency:

```
   octave
/usr/libexec/octave/6.2.0/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/octave-gui: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I tried the following:

```
sudo apt remove octave
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install octave
```

Same issue. I think Debian Bullseye only supports QT 6. Any ideas? I should mention this is Debian running on Windows using WSL

```
cat /etc/debian_version
```

> `11.3`

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

> `PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"` 
> `NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"`
> `VERSION_ID="11" VERSION="11 (bullseye)"` 
> `VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye`

Comment: You could ask at the octave mailing list or check the bugtracker to see if this is a known issue. By the way, the latest version is actually 7.1.0. You could try installing this from source (which is the best way to install octave anyway).

Comment: Thanks. so I did post but it turns out this is an error in Debian on WSL not Octave

Answer (score 2):

OK So I finally found the answer. This is an issue with WSL 1 in Windows. The fix is either upgrade to WSL 2 (not tested) or issue this command in WSL:

`sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5`

which worked!

Comment: This is very useful to know. Thanks for coming back to follow up. Mind if I change the title to something more "googleable?"